# How to export table data from Server Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server

In Visual Studio > Server Explorer, I can execute *Show table data* command to open a new tab with table data. Is there a quick way to export this data to something like CSV or Excel or do I need to use some 3rd party tool?

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a couple of years old, but you can do a query to get the data you want, and then click in the top left corner of the results pane to select it all. Then you can copy, paste into Excel and save as a .csv file.

Comment: The only downside, you don't get the column names in the result.. Which can be a big deal if you have a 50 column wide table.

Answer (score 2):

I know that Rich Hildred's answer is 4 years old, but now in VS 2019, after the selection of the result set, you can do a right click and then Script option, which generates Sql Inserts corresponding to the selected rows